# Matlab: binary numbers when used as booleans don't behave as expected?

Tags: matlab, binary, boolean

I'm trying to use the components of binary numbers as booleans in Matlab. Unfortunately they don't behave as I would expect them to. Take for example the following code:

```
for x = dec2bin(0:1)'
    x(1)  % the leading bit of x
    if logical(x(1))
        disp('yes')
    else
        disp('no')
    end
end
```

It outputs:

```
ans = 0
yes
ans = 1
yes
```

Does anybody know why that is, and how I can get it to output 'yes' when x(1) is 1, and 'no' otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dec2bin()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dec2bin.html) converts a number to a *string* representation, so `x(1)` obtains a *char*, not an *int*.  Therefore, it will be the ASCII value corresponding to `'0'` or `'1'` (48 or 49, respectively).  [`logical()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/logical.html) simply tests whether its argument is non-zero, which is true in both cases.

The solution is simply to use [`bitget()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) instead.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC the output of `dec2bin` is a string, not a number. So you are not getting `0` or `1`, but rather `'0'` or `'1'`

Try

```
if( strncmp(x(1),'1',1) )
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

In this case bitget indeed appears to be the most practical solution as pointed out by @Oli
, however a general alternative to change a string into the corresponding array of values is substracting the character value of zero.

```
for x = dec2bin(0:1)'
    x(1)  % the leading bit of x
    if x(1) - '0' 
        disp('yes')
    else
        disp('no')
    end
end
```